# SQL: get a list of accounts that have "Work requests" that have not been completed

Tags: sql

I'm tring to come up with a query that gets a list of accounts that have "Work requests" that have not been completed.

My query below gets me all of the accounts with "work request" "received" and "completed" but I only want the ones with received more times the completed.

```
SELECT n.incident_no,
   e.event_sub_type,
   COUNT (*) qty
FROM tb_event e,
 tb_incident n,
 vius_def d
WHERE e.incident_id = n.incident_id
 AND n.incident_id = d.incident_id
 AND EXISTS
 (SELECT 0
 FROM TB_EVENT e
 WHERE e.event_type = 'wrk req'
   AND e.event_sub_type = 'received'
   AND e.incident_id = n.incident_id)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 0
 FROM TB_EVENT e
 WHERE e.event_type = 'wrk req'
   AND e.event_sub_type IN ('received',
                            'completed')
   AND e.incident_id = n.incident_id)
AND e.event_type = 'wrk req'
AND d.incident_status_pd='o'
GROUP BY n.incident_no,
     e.event_sub_type
ORDER BY n.incident_no
```

This is the current answer to the query above

```
------------------------------------
incident_no event_sub_type  qty
------------------------------------
2008099999  COMPLETED   2
2008099999  RECEIVED    1
2013123456  RECEIVED    1
2014141414  COMPLETED   1
2014141414  RECEIVED    2
2016111111  RECEIVED    1
```

I only want to ones that have received more times than completed

This is what I would like as the answer to the query above

```
------------------------------------
incident_no event_sub_type  qty
------------------------------------
2013123456  RECEIVED    1
2014141414  RECEIVED    2
2016111111  RECEIVED    1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is another case where using old style joins make it harder to understand what is actually going on -- as you can see the sub-query here is functionally the same as yours -- but much simpler (and by simpler I mean simpler to read) without both the EXISTS.  Then using it as a sub-query to compare the totals is trivial.

```
  SELECT incident_no, 'RECEIVED' as event_sub_type, R_COUNT as qty
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT n.incident_no,
           e.event_sub_type,
           SUM(CASE WHEN lower(e.event_sub_type) = 'recieved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS R_COUNT,
           SUM(CASE WHEN lower(e.event_sub_type) = 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C_COUNT
    FROM tb_event e
    JOIN tb_incident n ON e.incident_id = n.incident_id AND lower(e.event_sub_type) IN ('received', 'completed')
    JOIN vius_def d ON n.incident_id = d.incident_id
    WHERE e.event_type = 'wrk req' AND d.incident_status_pd='o'
    GROUP BY n.incident_no
  ) X
  WHERE R_COUNT > C_COUNT
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I appreciate any help I can get as I am self thought through videos and tutorials on the web and probably don’t know the correct way of coding in SQL. I’m just muddling through. I’ll test your query and let you know how it works.
Thanks again and have a nice day.